# pthreads "double free or corruption (out)" error

Tags: c, parallel-processing, pthreads

I'm trying to do matrix multiplication using pthreads, 
but somehow I'm getting "double free or corruption (out)" error.

```
typedef struct {
    double *my_x;
    double *my_y;
    double my_dot_prod;
    double *global_dot_prod;
    pthread_mutex_t *mutex;
    int my_vec_len;
} dot_product_t;

void *serial_dot_product(void *arg) {
    dot_product_t *dot_data;
    int i;

    dot_data = arg;

    for(i=0; i<dot_data->my_vec_len; i++)
        dot_data->my_dot_prod += dot_data->my_x[i]*dot_data->my_y[i];

    pthread_mutex_lock(dot_data->mutex);
    *(dot_data->global_dot_prod) += dot_data->my_dot_prod;
    pthread_mutex_unlock(dot_data->mutex);
    pthread_exit(NULL);
}

int main() {
    double *x, *y, dot_prod;
    pthread_t *working_thread;
    dot_product_t *thrd_dot_prod_data;
    void *status;
    pthread_mutex_t *mutex_dot_prod;

    int num_of_thrds;
    int vec_len;
    int subvec_len;

    double** A;
    double** B;
    double** C;

    int i=0;
    int j=0;
    int n;

    printf ("Enter matrix dimension n: ");
    scanf(" %d", &n);

// Matrix A - memory allocation
    A =(double **)malloc(n*sizeof(double *));
    A[0] = (double *)malloc(n*n*sizeof(double));
    A[0] = (double *)malloc(n*n*sizeof(double));
    if(!A) {
        printf("memory failed \n");
        exit(1);
    }
    for(i=1; i<n; i++) {
        A[i] = A[0]+i*n;
        if (!A[i]) {
            printf("memory failed \n");
            exit(1);
        }
    }

// Matrix B - memory allocation
    B =(double **)malloc(n*sizeof(double *));
    B[0] = (double *)malloc(n*n*sizeof(double));

    if(!B) {
        printf("memory failed \n");
        exit(1);
    }

    for(i=1; i<n; i++) {
        B[i] = B[0]+i*n;
        if (!B[i]){
            printf("memory failed \n");
            exit(1);
        }
    }

// Matrix C - memory allocation
    C =(double **)malloc(n*sizeof(double *));
    C[0] = (double *)malloc(n*n*sizeof(double));
    if(!C) {
        printf("memory failed \n");
        exit(1);
    }

    for(i=1; i<n; i++) {
        C[i] = C[0]+i*n;
        if (!C[i]) {
            printf("memory failed \n");
            exit(1);
        }
    }

    for(i=0; i<n; i++) {
        for(j=0; j<n; j++) {
            A[i][j] = 1.0;
            B[i][j] = 1.0;
            C[i][j] = 0.0;
        }
    }

    printf("Number of processors = ");
    if(scanf("%d", &num_of_thrds) < 1 || num_of_thrds > MAXTHRDS){
        printf("Check input for number of processors. Bye.\n");
        return -1;
    }
    printf("Vector length = ");
    if(scanf("%d", &vec_len)<1 || vec_len > n){
        printf("Check input for vector length. Bye.\n");
        return -1;
    }
    subvec_len = vec_len/num_of_thrds;

    working_thread = malloc(num_of_thrds*sizeof(pthread_t));
    thrd_dot_prod_data=malloc(num_of_thrds*sizeof(dot_product_t));
    mutex_dot_prod = malloc(sizeof(pthread_mutex_t));
    pthread_mutex_init(mutex_dot_prod, NULL);

    int k = 0;
    int l = 0;

    for(j=0;j<n;j++){
        for(k=0;k<n;k++){
            x = A[j];
            y = B[k];
            for(i=0; i<num_of_thrds; i++){
                thrd_dot_prod_data[i].my_x = x + i*subvec_len;
                thrd_dot_prod_data[i].my_y = y + i*subvec_len;
                thrd_dot_prod_data[i].global_dot_prod = &dot_prod;
                thrd_dot_prod_data[i].mutex = mutex_dot_prod;
                thrd_dot_prod_data[i].my_vec_len =
                        (i==num_of_thrds-1)?vec_len-(num_of_thrds-1)*subvec_len:subvec_len;
                pthread_create(&working_thread[i], NULL, serial_dot_product,(void*)&thrd_dot_prod_data[i]);
            }
            for(i=0; i<num_of_thrds; i++)
                pthread_join(working_thread[i], &status);
             C[j][k] = dot_prod;
            dot_prod = 0.0;

        }
    }

    for(i=0;i<n;i++) {
        for(j=0;j<n;j++){
            printf("%lf ", C[i][j]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }

    free(A);
    free(B[0]);
    free(B);
    free(C[0]);
    free(C);
    free(x);
    free(y);
    free(working_thread);
    free(thrd_dot_prod_data);
    pthread_mutex_destroy(mutex_dot_prod);
    free(mutex_dot_prod);
}
```

The serial_dot_product function is the one I'm using for each row on the A matrix and column on each B matrix and then assign the resulting return value to C[j][k]. However, when I do run this, I get this error.
[Error image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ex3ey.png)

It gives me a matrix as you can see before the actual 'double free or corruption' error, but it's wrong.

Comment: Can you run this under Valgrind (memcheck for the memory issues and helgrind/DRD for threads)?

Comment: @Stargateur Ah sorry. I was just a bit desperate, I guess. I was researching all day and somehow I didn't find an answer. This was my last resort.

Comment: @Paul Floyd Thank you for the suggestion. Unfortunately, I'm not well versed in that kind of thing.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to show us what kind of debugging you've done.  I expect you to have run your [mcve] within Valgrind or a similar checker, and to have investigated with a debugger such as GDB, for example.  Ensure you've enabled a full set of compiler warnings, too.  What did the tools tell you, and what information are they missing?  And read Eric Lippert's [How to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/).

Comment: Please [edit] your code to reduce it to a [mcve] of your problem.  Your current code includes much that is peripheral to your problem - a minimal sample normally looks similar to a good unit test: only performing one task, with input values specified for reproducibility.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several problems here.

You create an array of `n` elements by allocating `A`.  Then you create a two dimensional array of `n` elements and attach it to the first element in `A`.  Twice.  **The first allocation is lost, and is a memory leak.**

You do the same thing for `B` and `C`, without the double allocation.

You then operate on `A`, `B` and `C` as though they are two dimensional arrays, which they are not, **so you are writing to "random" places in memory** (i.e., not where you have memory allocated) which is corrupting the heap.  **You should be allocating `A`, `B` and `C` as two dimensional arrays.**

When you finish, you don't free the `A[0]` array, only the `A` array.  **This leaks the A[0] allocation.**  You correctly free the `B[0]` and `C[0]` arrays before releasing the `B` and `C` arrays.  **Then you free `x` and `y`, which were never allocated** - they only refer to allocated memory.  **This is the source of your "double free" error.**

Comment: Thank you. I took away the free(x) and free(y) and it worked. Just have to implement it to properly give me the proper resulting matrix multiplication.

Comment: I hope you fixed the other errors I pointed out.  You should also mark answers as "accepted" when they solve your problems, that's part of what makes StackOverflow work.